# In flex, how to trigger mouseevent when the focus is on TextInput?

Tags: apache-flex, mouseevent, textinput

In flex, I am using the following:

mx:TextInput mouseOver="tester(event)"

It works fine. My pointer goes over the textInput and it calls the function. But when I click inside the textInput to enter some text( focus is on the textInput)  and then move the mouse (not taking mouse pointer outside of the boundary of textinput), the mouseover event is not trigerred.

If I use click event, then even if I am entering text ( or the focus is on the textinput) and then click, it will call the function.

How can I call the `tester` function on mouseover  when the focus is on textInput?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mouseOver event fires when the mouse is moved over the control.

Maybe you want to try the [mouseMove](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/flash/display/InteractiveObject.html#event:mouseMove) event which will fire every time the mouse moves?

Keep in mind that mouseEvents and focusEvents are not inherently related.  I would expect the mouseOver event to fire when the mouse rolls over your textInput regardless of whether or not that textInput has the focus.